# samtools/sed for editing bam file

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

I have the following sed command that change the chromosome name:

```
for file in /myoldpath/*.bam; do
  filename=echo $file | cut -d "." -f 1
  samtools view -H $file | sed -e 's/SN:([0-9XY])/SN:chr\1/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' | \
  samtools reheader - $file > /mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam
done
```

My question is how to insert the result in a new path while keeping the variable `$filename` as part of every new file name? It always insert the result in `/myoldpath/` or literally `filename.chr.bam` in the `/mynewpath/`
 am I missing something in the syntax of that part `$file > /mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning to the `filename` variable, you may use the `basename` utility like so:

```
filename="$( basename "$file" .bam )"
```

This will give `filename` the value `myfile` if `$file` is, for example `/my/data/myfile.bam` (i.e., it will remove any path element as well as the specified suffix).

You could even use

```
filename="/mynewpath/$( basename "$file" .bam )_chr.bam"
```

or

```
filename="$( printf '/mynewpath/%s_chr.bam' "$( basename "$file" .bam )" )"
```

With the last two examples, you would later use `"$filename"` rather than `"/mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam"` for the redirection.

As for the `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/SN:([0-9XY])/SN:chr\1/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/'
```

This will insert the string `chr` into `SN:X` where `X` is a chromosome name, turning it into `SN:chrX`.  However, you will need to either use `\( ... \)` instead of `( ... )` for the capture group, or add the `-E` option to the invocation of `sed`, or you will get an error saying "invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS" (with GNU `sed`) or "\1 not defined in the RE" (with BSD `sed`).